# How to manage Looper thread needed in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to encapsulate in an `Observable` a logic that queries a `ContentProvider` and also subscribes `ContentProvider` cursor to supply continuous updates.

As the observable does IO work I need to subscribe it in `Schedulers.io()`. The problem with that is that then I can't register a `ContentObserver` because it needs a looper prepared thread.

What is the recommended way to manage that and **encapsulate** it in a single `Observable`.

Code to illustrate that:

```
public Observable<Integer> unreadCountObservable() {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        new UnreadCountObservable(subscriber);
    });
}

private class UnreadCountObservable {
    private Subscriber subscriber;

    public UnreadCountObservable(Subscriber subscriber) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
        Cursor cursor = queryUnread(subscriber);
        cursor.registerContentObserver(observer);
        subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> {
            cursor.unregisterContentObserver(observer);
            cursor.close();
        }));
    }

    @NonNull
    private Cursor queryUnread(Subscriber subscriber) {
        Cursor cursor = contextProvider.getContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI),SMS_PROJECTION,SMS_SELECTION_UNREAD,SMS_PROJECTION,null);
        if(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Integer count = cursor.getInt(0);
            subscriber.onNext(count);
        } else {
            subscriber.onNext(0);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    private ContentObserver observer = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            Timber.d("New sms data changed");
            queryUnread(subscriber);
        }
    };
}
```

**Note 1** The problem with the above code is that it can't be called with `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()` due to the registerObserver, and if it's called it mainThread then the queries also run on them)

**Note:** Encapsulating all in a single `Observable` is a key requirement and the motive of this question

My best idea now is to create a HandlerThread for activity where I use the Observable and use the looper from that thread. But want to know if there are better alternatives, and if making a generic scheduler (e.g looperIoScheduler()) makes sense on can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

In `Observable` chain you can change the thread as often as you wish. Have a look [here](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html).

The function `rx.Observable#observeOn(rx.Scheduler)` can be in any place inside the chain. Try to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
Observable.just(cursor)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map((Cursor) -> {
                cursor.registerContentObserver(observer);
                return cursor;
            }
        }).observeOn(Schedulers.io());
subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> {
        cursor.unregisterContentObserver(observer);
        cursor.close();
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you expand your sample to include also cursor creation and sending updates from the observer. Because I think that complete code won't be easily readable.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so why won't this work?

```
public Observable<Integer> unreadCountObservable() {
    return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        new UnreadCountObservable(subscriber);
    }))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

Comment: It doesn't works. SubscribeOn goes up in the subscription chain, it doesn't matter if it's the first or the last sentence of the chain. That way defer run on io thread and UnreadCountObservable constructor also runs on it.