# Have some trouble with thread work

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java2

My event emmiter class has code:

```
 private val socketListeners: ArrayList<SocketContentListener> = ArrayList()

  //add listener here
 override fun subscribe(socketListener: SocketContentListener) {
        socketListeners.add(socketListener)
    }

       private fun getSocketConnectListener()
                : SocketContentListener {
            /**
             * Post received messages to listeners via Handler
             * because handler helps to set all messages in order on main thread.
             */
            return object : SocketContentListener {

                override fun onUdpServerListenerCreated(inetAddress: InetAddress?, port: Int) {
                    val subscribers = ArrayList<SocketContentListener>(socketListeners)
                    for (listener in subscribers) {
                        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post({ listener.onUdpServerListenerCreated(inetAddress, port) })
                    }
            }
        }
```

I try to crete Observable:

```
val udpObservable = Observable.create<Int> { emitter ->
        val listener = object : SocketListener() {
            override fun onUdpServerListenerCreated(inetAddress: InetAddress, port: Int) {
                emitter.onNext(port)
                emitter.onComplete()
            }

        }
        //add listener here
        socketSource.subscribe(listener)
        emitter.setCancellable { socketSource.unSubscribe(listener) }
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext { Log.d("123-thread", "current is: " + Thread.currentThread().name) }
            .onErrorReturn { throw ConnectionException(it) }
            .subscribe()
```

But during test instead of the expected `RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 thread` work i saw

```
  D/123-thread: current is:-> main
```

So can You help me? please. Where is my mistake? How do I achieve the desired RxCachedThreadScheduler thread for rx chains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for creating Observable will be executed on the scheduler, there is no implicit context change anywhere.

Your events arrive from the listener on the main thread. Then you send them to the emitter on the same thread.

> So, subscription go on Schedulers io Thread, but emitters go on Main Thread

[image: So, subscription go on io, but emitters go on main]
  
[image: emitters go on main]

So the solution is to add `observerOn(Schedulers.newThread())` after Observable create. [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39449556/6352712)

```
val udpObservable = Observable.create<Int> { emitter ->
        val listener = object : SocketListener() {
            override fun onUdpServerListenerCreated(inetAddress: InetAddress, port: Int) {
                emitter.onNext(port)
                emitter.onComplete()
            }

        }
        //add listener here
        socketSource.subscribe(listener)
        emitter.setCancellable { socketSource.unSubscribe(listener) }
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

      //need add this for work with emmit data on background 
     .observerOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnNext { Log.d("123-thread", "current is: " + Thread.currentThread().name) }
            .onErrorReturn { throw ConnectionException(it) }
            .subscribe()
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergey, next time try to use code instead of images. You could use comments to annotate things like you've done with red arrows.

Comment: @GoRoS I will consider your fidbek, think you are right